# Recyclerview is not displaying anything, any ideas? Using FirestoreUI RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

The code Below I seem to have done everything needed, but the recyclerview is just not being populated.

I even put the Log on OnDateChange to see if it's called, and it was called once on the LogCat after I ran it on my Galaxy S6. Also, the database is public.

```
RecyclerView chat_view;
EditText message_text;

CollectionReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("stage2");
Query query = reference.orderBy("timestamp");
FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage,ChatHolder> adapter=null;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    //initializing, called below
    init();
}





private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage,ChatHolder> newAdapter() {
    final FirestoreRecyclerOptions options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
            .setQuery(query,ChatMessage.class)
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)                
                            .build();

    return new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, ChatHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public ChatHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
           View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_item,parent,false);
            //if(((ChatMessage)options.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(viewType)).)
            return new ChatHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(ChatHolder holder, int position, ChatMessage model) {         




            //displaying the message and users into the recyclerview
            holder.user_msg.setText(model.getMessage());
            holder.user_date.setText(model.getDate());
            holder.user_name.setText(model.getName());

        }




        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {
            Log.d("TAG", "YESSIR");

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            super.onError(e);
        }
    };




}

private void init(){
    chat_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chat_view);
    chat_view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    chat_view.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = newAdapter();
    chat_view.setAdapter(adapter);




    message_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_text);
    message_text.setEnabled(appUtils.isSignedIn());
    findViewById(R.id.send_button).setEnabled(appUtils.isSignedIn());




}
```

So, there we have it, I have no idea what the problem could be at this point. I am using the most recent Firestore UI dependency as well.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have done everything necessary..using `FirestoreRecycleroptions` and inflating the layout in `onCreateViewHolder`.

For `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` to be able to have the data on the activity, then you need to listen to any changes in `onStart()` which is after `onCreate()`. Also
in `onStop` you can stop listening.

```
    @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

Comment: Oh, I did that. I tried both that and the LifecycleOwner method on recyclerOptions, and same problem.

Comment: @BaldricNguena try and move your collectionreference and query and your firestore.getinstance after setContentView just declare them as global variables but do not initialize them before setContentView

Comment: I figured it out, there error was at the query = reference.orderBy("timestamp");